# .FindNext keeps returning to the first match, instead of the next

Tags: excel, vba

I have a SourceFile.xlsm that contains an X number of field definitions and their contents:

[image: SourceFile]

I want to put the contents of these fields into a TargetFile.xlsx, that may contain 0 or more of those field definitions:

[image: TargetFile]

The expected end result would be this:

[image: expected end result]

But the actual end result is always this:

[image: actual end result]

And that is because this line in the code below:

```
Set source_range = sourceSheet.Cells.FindNext(source_range)
```

always keeps coming back to the first occurrence (cell B5, containing "[Field 1]"), instead of the next (cell B6, containing "[Field 2]"):

```
Function CopyFromSourceToTarget()
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim targetWB As Workbook

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

Dim source_range As Range
Dim target_range As Range

Dim FirstFound_source As String
Dim FirstFound_target As String


Set sourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set targetWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\TargetFile.xlsx")

For Each sourceSheet In sourceWB.Worksheets
    Set source_range = sourceSheet.Cells.Find("[", LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not source_range Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound_source = source_range.Address
        
        Debug.Print source_range.Value
        
        Do
        
            sourceWB.Activate
            source_range.Select
            
            For Each targetSheet In targetWB.Worksheets
                Set target_range = targetSheet.Cells.Find(source_range.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not target_range Is Nothing Then
                    FirstFound_target = target_range.Address
                    Do
                        target_range.FormulaR1C1 = CStr(source_range.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                        Set target_range = targetSheet.Cells.FindNext(target_range)
                        If target_range Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    Loop Until target_range.Address = FirstFound_target
                End If
            Next
            
            Set source_range = sourceSheet.Cells.FindNext(source_range)
            
            Debug.Print source_range.Value
        Loop Until source_range.Address = FirstFound_source
        
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I've tried several options, but all to no avail. Hopefully, someone here can help me along, because this seemingly very simple issue is driving me nuts.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... I mean `FindNext` always go back to the first occurrence, **if no other match has been found**. That's why you used `FirstFound_target = target_range.Address` followed by `Loop Until target_range.Address = FirstFound_target`. This will exit the `Loop` when `FindNext` reaches the initial cell address. And  `If target_range Is Nothing Then Exit Do` is useless. Since the function will go back to the first address, **it will never return `Nothing``**. So, please, check if the cells **you think should  be found** do really contain what you think they should.

Comment: I mean, you maybe need adding more parameters to the initial `Cells.Find(source_range.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` function (`LookAt`, `MatchCase` etc.). `FindNext` searches using **its parameters**...

Comment: Can you even run multiples `Find`s at the same time? Don't the second `Find` in the target sheet overwrite the first in the source sheet? (just like you cannot run multiple `Dir`s at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
Set source_range = sourceSheet.Cells.FindNext(source_range)
```

try this line:

```
Set source_range = sourceSheet.Cells.Find(What:="[", After:=source_range, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I'd also add some more options to the `Find` like `LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False`, but it might not be necessary. Up to you.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I'm extremely relieved, because this problem had been bugging me for days now. And yes, I know about the other Find Options, but in this particular case (I tried them all) they were irrelevant.

Comment: Just be sure that a previous search won't mess with the incode search. It will most likely not, but better safe than sorry.